# Cannot join feature layer with SQL Server table with query built in it in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, sql-server, query, query-layer

I need to join a feature layer with a SQL Server View with a common field in ArcMap. The View was successfully added to ArcMap as data table with some query built on it from Query Builder.

When I tried to make join on those two layers it returned nothing in the attribute table.

However, if I modified the view definition with exactly the same query in SQL Server, the View added to ArcMap and joined with the feature layer returned records in the attribute table.

I would like to enable the user to build their query on the added View as table in ArcMap rather than currently having to do it in View definition on the SQL Server side.

Just wonder if anybody came across the problem before. Is there any workaround for it?

Thanks

Alex